# rhn_register through HTTP Proxy with Authentication

Tags: redhat, yum

Is there any limitation to the proxy authentication support of rhn_register?

The proxy of the network I'm on sends the follow 407:

```
HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required ( The ISA Server requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied.  )
Via: 1.1 VANESSA
Proxy-Authenticate: Negotiate
Proxy-Authenticate: Kerberos    
Proxy-Authenticate: NTLM
```

It seems that rhn_register is not able to any of the authentication schemes above.

Any advise?

Answer (score 3):

- RedHat Network

  1. Open /etc/sysconfig/rhn/up2date for editing
  2. Change the following:

  From:

  > enableProxy=0

  To:

  > +enableProxy=1

  3. Add Following missing lines, if you use user name and password authentication
     enableProxyAuth[comment]=To use an authenticated proxy or not
     enableProxyAuth=1
  4. Enter the user's password for the http proxy where it states the following:

     > proxyPassword=
  5. Enter the user's username for the http proxy where it states the following:

     > proxyUser=
  6. Enter the URL for the proxy server, in host:port format, in the following line:

     > httpProxy=
  7. Save the file.
- Wget

  1. Open /root/.bach_profile for editing
  2. Add the following:

     > export http_proxy="http://proxyUser:proxyPassword@httpProxy"
- Yum

  1. Open /etc/yum.conf for editing
  2. Add the following:

     > proxy=http://httpProxy
     >   proxy_username=proxyUser
     >   proxy_password=proxyPassword

Answer (score 1):

There are two Knowledgebase articles which answer your question:

[How can I access Red Hat Network (RHN), RHN Satellite or RHN proxy via an HTTP proxy?](https://access.redhat.com/kb/docs/DOC-9826)

[Attempting to register my Red Hat Enterprise Linux server with Red Hat Network through a Microsoft ISA proxy fails. How can I resolve this?](https://access.redhat.com/kb/docs/DOC-1979)

Your RHN account is used to access the articles.

The second article mentions that NTLM is not directly supported by Red Hat, however there is a project which can be used to make it work.

Quick summary, edit the /etc/sysconfig/rhn/up2date file and enter the appropriate proxy information in there, making sure to set "enableProxy=1"

Answer (score 0):

when you run :

configure-proxy.sh

did you try entering the proxy server in the form :

http://username:password@proxyaddress:3128

?

It looks like your proxy server requires Kerberos ticket rather than a straight username and password, does the ISA server require domain membership? This may be more difficult than straight HTTP proxy auth. I'm pretty sure rhn_proxy supports a http proxy with username and password but I couldn't find it in a quick look for the docs.

Comment: Yes, I did.  It seems that rhn_register only support Basic HTTP Authentication.